# Count along with date condition for each id

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

i have data in 2 Sql tables/Pandas DF

1st containing the user id and discount date like below

[image]

the other table contains all purchase events

[image]

How can i get the user id wise status giving counts before the discount and after the discount.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.userid,
       SUM(p.purchase_date < d.discount_date) Before_discount,
       SUM(p.purchase_date >= d.discount_date) After_discount,
       COUNT(*) total_purchases
FROM purchases p INNER JOIN discounts d
ON d.userid = p.userid
GROUP BY p.userid
```

Change the table names `purchases` and `discounts` to the actual ones.

Comment: Thanks, what if both of them are Pandas DataFrame?